# How to reach the UK ministry of education's website for verifying an international school's accreditation?

Tags: school, united-kingdom

I have an ISN number for an international school that claims it is UK accredited, and I would like to reach the UK ministry of education's website made for verifying the accreditation of international schools.
By the way, the school is an elementary school.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have a ministry of education - there is a Department for Education, but they do have an list of international schools registered:

http://orderline.education.gov.uk/international/Public/schools.aspx

They have an email address that you may find useful

internationalschools@education.gov.uk

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, it was very helpful. The school has been using this ISN number to scam people and make them think it is an accredited school. As far as I can see from the link that the number is just a number used to have access to the tests from the department, as it reads here "**From this site international schools are able to purchase printed copies of the 2014 National Curriculum tests and optional tests, for reference and administration.**"

Comment: @learner According to [this page](http://www.education.gov.uk/schools/teachingandlearning/assessment/a00197992/international-schools), that's the _only_ thing it's used for. That information is useful enough to warrant an answer of its own. You could answer your own question, or perhaps Rory Alsop would like to expand their answer.